# quartz grails multi-entity environment

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I have a web-app (grails 2.3.5, quartz plugin) with multiple users. Now I want that my users can schedule jobs using quartz. I wonder what the best approach is to separate Triggers from one user from the triggers from another user.

e.g. provide a list of all scheduled tasks for a given user

Are there any recommendations how to make this differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing some scheme for naming your triggers would likely be the best approach here. That way you can query the triggers for a job and filter them by some type of matching pattern.

It's really up to you to decide how you want to manage the visibility and management of the triggers. Using the trigger name seems to be the most logical approach in my own opinion.

Alternatively, you could build a framework (e.g. Domain model) that relates the triggers to a user.

**Update**

In light of the content of your comment I'd like to offer you a glimpse into how you can dynamically add a trigger to an existing job. This is only an example to help you get further down the path of accomplishing the goal you have.

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder
import org.quartz.Trigger
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder
...
def jobManagerService

String cronExpression = ... // whatever the expression is

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("UniqueNameOfYourTriggerHere-UserId")
    .withPriority(6)
    .forJob("com.example.package.JobClassNameJob", "groupName")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
    .build()

// if you need job parameters
trigger.jobDataMap.putAll([param1: 'example'])

jobManagerService.getQuartzScheduler().scheduleJob(trigger)
```

Comment: When I look at the tables from quartz in my database I see a table called QUARTZ_CALENDER. Would it be possible to use one calender per user and do the separation this way? Just a guess.

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the backing data for Quartz directly via the database. That's internal to Quartz itself. If you do, I have no idea what the results will be. Typically you will want to use the Quartz provided services and factories to add/remove/pause/resume triggers associated with jobs and let it manage the datastore itself. I overestimated your understanding of Quartz and thus my answer assumes you already knew how to manage dynamically scheduled jobs but were seeking advice on how to segment them.

Comment: I've added some more information to the answer that may help you further along these lines.